# How can you quickly find the span of the eigenvectors of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I already know the long-winded way to find the span of an eigenspace. Its to find how many invariant lines (from the matrix that go through the origin) face different directions, and the number of different lines facing different directions is the dimension of the eigenspace.

I know that if there are no repeated eigenvalues, then the eigenspace spans the same dimention, but if there are repeated eigenvalues, the eigenspace can differ (not always since having repeated eigenvalues doesnt always imply a smaller dimention for the eigenspace).

What is a quick method to find the eigenspace of a matrix because I want to be able to tell if a matrix is diagonalizable or not?

Comment: step 1. Find the eigenvalues through characteristic polynomial. The multiplicity as roots is called algebraic multiplicity. 
step 2. check the rank of $A-\lambda I$ for any of those eigevalues. It is called geometric multiplicity.
step 3. if geometric and algebraic multiplicities match for every eigenvalue, the matrix is diagonalizable

Comment: @Exodd the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ is ($n$- (the rank of $A-\lambda I$)), where $n$ is the dimension of the matrix.

Comment: There are also special cases: symmetric matrices and projections are always diagonalizable, for instance.

Comment: @user3257842 yeah, I meant the nullrank

Comment: If the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial is non-zero, then all the eigenvalues are distinct,  and the matrix is diagonalizable . 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Definition